# return to default form behavior

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can we return to default form behavior ?
I have a form created with both static HTML and dynamically generated HTML (with javascript using jquery) and I want to do some treatments before sending my form.

To do so, I stop the default behavior with e.preventDefault(). But after my treatments, I want to return to default behavior for the form (especially for the required inputs)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to remove `preventDefault()`? It should do the stuff you want anyway.

```
var form = $('#my-form');

form.submit(function() {
  //doing my treatments

  //then post the form
});
```

Comment: to remove preventDefault() ? what do you mean ?
Anyway, indeed it solved my problem... And I realize how easy it was... ^^Thanks

Comment: @Roshyo event.preventDefault() is useful when you want to prevent the default action for an event, for instance when you click on a link and you dont want it to take you anywhere.